# Declaring both directory and inner files in a Bazel rule

Tags: bazel, starlark

I want a Bazel rule which creates a directory, takes a bunch of files, and creates an ISO out of that directory (the ISO is the intended output here, the other files are just byproducts).

```py
# Declare root directory
root_directory = ctx.actions.declare_directory("root_directory")

# Call mkdir to create root directory
create_root_directory_arguments = ctx.actions.args()
create_root_directory_arguments.add(root_directory.path)
ctx.actions.run(
    outputs = [root_directory],
    arguments = [create_root_directory_arguments],
    executable = "mkdir",
)

...

# Declare and collect inner files
copy_output_files = []
for image_file in image_files:
    copy_output_file = ctx.actions.declare_file(image_file_path)
    copy_output_files.append(copy_output_file)

# Call cp to copy the inner files into the root directory
copy_arguments = ctx.actions.args()
copy_arguments.add("-r")
copy_arguments.add("-t", root_directory.path)
for image_file in image_files:
    copy_arguments.add(image_file.path)
ctx.actions.run(
    inputs = [root_directory],
    outputs = copy_output_files,
    arguments = [copy_arguments],
    executable = "cp",
)

...
```

The problem is that if I declare the directory `abc`, I cannot declare the file `abc/def` - I get an exception.

What is the intended solution here? Should I declare the folder alone? Just the files? How would I achieve the `File` object for the `run` call other than declaring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: write a shell script and make all of what you've showed one action, with the ISO file as the only output. Bazel will create the parent directories of each of your outputs before running your action, you don't need to do that. Don't use `ctx.actions.declare_directory`.

I have two common approaches for temporary files:

- Using suffixes of one of the outputs. This could produce conflicts, but in practice it's generally fine. Something like this:

  ```bash
  OUTPUT="$1"
  rm -rf "${OUTPUT}.temp"
  mkdir "${OUTPUT}.temp"
  echo abc > "${OUTPUT}.temp/xyz"
  echo abc2 > "${OUTPUT}.temp/xyz2"
  make_the_thing "${OUTPUT}.temp"
  mv "${OUTPUT}.temp/something.iso" "${OUTPUT}"
  ```

  Removing any temporary files beforehand is important for your rule to work robustly without sandboxing. If you don't do that, it's easy to write rules that work with sandboxing, but fail in different ways when you try running them without sandboxing to debug.
- `$TMPDIR` via a tool like `mktemp` or [tempfile](https://docs.rs/tempfile/latest/tempfile/) or otherwise designed to robustly create unique temporary files or folders. You cannot use hard-coded paths like `/tmp/my_unique_thing`, because it is possible for your rule to run simultaneously in multiple configurations, or concurrent builds in different output roots. Even including the PID like `/tmp/my_unique_thing_$$` (shell syntax for substituting in the PID) doesn't work, because some sandboxes result in every action using the same PID.

Directory artifacts (the thing created by `ctx.actions.declare_directory`) are an advanced feature. I've used and created a lot of Bazel rules, and I've never found it useful. It's only useful for situations like a tool that produces a directory with 10 files named based on hashes of the input file contents, and it expects those same 10 files with the same names that will differ every build to be passed into a later step. It looks useful for temporary files and packaging at first, but it doesn't really work for those.

For reference, I usually manage files for packaging via `pkg_tar`, with custom rules that translate tarballs directly into the final outputs. Anything that extracts a tarball and then re-packages it tends to run into issues with file permissions (actions runs unprivileged so it can't make a file `0400 root:root` for example) and reproducibility (timestamps and sorting), but you can do that if you want.